# How does this one stream command read in an entire file in c++?

Tags: c++, ifstream, stringstream, streambuf

Given this:

```
auto f = std::ifstream{file};
if (f) {
    std::stringstream stream;
    stream << f.rdbuf();
    return stream.str();
}
return std::string{};
```

I don't see why it works.
I don't know what type f is, because it says auto, but apparently you can check that for non-zero-ness.
But when the file is large, like 2 gig, the delay in running happens in
this line:

```
    stream << f.rdbuf();
```

The documentation says rdbuf() gets you the pointer to the ifstream's internal buffer. So in order for it to read the entire file, the buffer would have to size the file, and load it all in in one shot. But by the time the stream << happens, rdbuf() has to already be set, or it won't be able to return a point.
I would expect the constructor to do that in this case, but it's obviously lazy loaded, because reading in the entire file on construction would be bad for every other use case, and the delay is in the stream << command.

Any thoughts? All other stack overflow references to reading in a file to a string always loop in some way.

If there's some buffer involved, which obviously there is, how big can it get? What if it is 1 byte, it would surely be slow.

Adorable c++ is very opaque, bad for programmers who have to know what's going on under the covers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a function of how `operator<<` is defined on `ostream`s when the argument is a `streambuf`. As long as the `streambuf` isn't a null pointer, it extracts characters from the input sequence controlled by the `streambuf` and inserts them into `*this` until one of the following conditions are met (see [`operator<<` overload note #9](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt)):

> - end-of-file occurs on the input sequence;
> - inserting in the output sequence fails (in which case the character to be inserted is not extracted);
> - an exception occurs (in which case the exception is caught).

Basically, the `ostream` (which `stringstream` inherits from) knows how to exercise a `streambuf` to pull all the data from the file it's associated with. It's an idiomatic, but as you note, not intuitive, way to slurp a whole file. The `streambuf` isn't actually buffering all the data here (as you note, reading the whole file into the buffer would be bad in the general case), it's just that it has the necessary connections to adjust the buffered window as an `ostream` asks for more (and more, and more) data.

`if (f)` works because `ifstream` has [an overload for `operator bool`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) that is implicitly invoked when the "truthiness" of the `ifstream` is tested that tells you if the file is in a failure state.

Comment: makes a lot more sense when you know that "Returns a pointer to the internal filebuf object." is not true.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your first question first:

`f` is of the type that's assigned to it, an `std::ifstream`, but that's a rather silly way to write it. One would usually write `std::ifstream f {...}`. A stream has an overloaded `operator bool ()` which gives you `!fail()`.

As for the second question: What `.rdbuf()` returns is a `streambuf` object. This object doesn't contain the whole file contents when it is returned. Instead, it provides an interface to access data, and this interface is used by the `stringstream stream`.

Comment: yeah, the docs don't exactly imply that, whatever I read, probably cplusplus.com said it returns a pointer to the stream's internal buffer.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/rdbuf/ and I quote "Returns a pointer to the internal filebuf object."

Comment: @stu True, `filebuf` is the specific subclass of `streambuf` that's used in file streams and is returned (by pointer) from their `rdbuf()` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
auto f = std::ifstream{file};
```

Type of `f` is `std::ifstream`.

```
stream << f.rdbuf();
```

`std::ifstream` maintains a buffer which you can get by `f.rdbuf()` and it does not load entire file in 1 shot. The loading happens when the above commands is called, `stringstream` will extract data from that buffer, and `ifstream` will perform loading as the buffer runs out of data.

You can manually set the buffer size by using [setbuf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/setbuf).